# How to expand Parent groups horizontally in ssrs reports instead of breaking the page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have cities  grouped by Countries, tablix hold the data and the parent group is (country),the (keep together) option is set to true on tablix properties, the width of tablix is approximately 30% of body width  , i want  to expand the data Horizontally to second column (if there is no space left vertically)  after the end of each group.

Comment: There is better chance of getting a correct answer if you provide code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-column reports are supported by SSRS.

Go to the Reports-Report Properties... menu. Click on the Layout tab and set the number of columns to how many columns you want on the page - in your example it would be 2. This will give you a column to lay out report objects on the left and a greyed-out column on the right that will be where your column on the left will repeat.

Your columns must be able to fit twice on the page allowing for margins. At 30% width you should be fine here.

However, the report renderer in your designer doesn't support multiple columns so you will only see one column in the designer. The HTML renderer also doesn't support multiple columns and you will only see one column for the report when deployed to the reporting services server and displayed as a web page.

To see a multiple column layout, you need to output your report to a renderer that supports multiple columns, such as PDF or a printer.